Evaluating $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{(i\ln 2)^i}{2^ii!}$
I seek the proof of the evaluation to the sum
$$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{(i\ln 2)^i}{2^ii!} = \frac{1}{1-\ln2}-1 \approx 2.25889.$$
It is almost a power series, if not for the $i$ in the bracket.
I have no idea how to proceed. I tried integrating and differentiating the summand (as it is apparently a common technique), but the $i^i$ term causes problems.
It might be related to the fact that the sum is equal to the geometric sum $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\ln^i2$.
Any solutions would be greatly appreciated.

I'm not sure what you mean by "it's almost a power series" and "I tried integrating and differentiating". There is no $x$ here, this is a number series

Use the following formula:
$$\mathrm{W}(-x)=-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{n^{n-1}}{n!}x^n,
\quad x\in(-1/e,1/e)$$
(for reference, see Derivation of the series for $W(x)$)
here $W$ is Lambert W function, then
$$xW'(-x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{n^{n}}{n!}x^n.$$
Take $x=\frac{\ln2}{2}\in(-1/e,1/e)$, we will get
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(n\ln 2)^n}{2^n\cdot n!}=\frac{\ln2}{2}W'\left(-\frac{\ln2}{2}\right).$$
Use
$$W\left(\frac{-\log(x)}{x}\right)=\log({x}^{-1}),\quad W'(z)=\frac{1}{z+e^{W(z)}},$$
( see $W\left(\frac{-\log(x)}{x}\right)=\log({x}^{-1})$)
we can get
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(n\ln 2)^n}{2^n\cdot n!}
=\frac{\ln2}{2}\frac{1}{-(\ln2)/2+e^{W(-(\ln2)/2)}}
=\frac{\ln2}{2}\frac{1}{\frac12-(\ln2)/2}
=\frac{\ln2}{1-\ln 2}.$$
For the reference of $W'(z)=\frac{1}{z+e^{W(z)}}$, we can refer Lambert W function

Nice answer and nice manipulation of Lambert function.

Does $(n)^n$ means simply $n^n$?

@
jjagmath
Yes, thank you, fixed it now!

This is too long for a comment.
For a quick approximation of the partial sums
$$a_i=\frac{i^i \,\left(\frac{\log (2)}{2}\right)^i}{i!}$$
Let $$\alpha=\log \left(\frac{1}{2} e \log (2)\right)$$
Using the asymptotics
$$a_i=\frac{e^{\alpha \,i}}{\sqrt{2 \pi } \sqrt{i}}\Bigg(1-\frac{1}{12\, i}+\frac{1}{288\,
   i^2}+\frac{139}{51840\,i^3}-\frac{571}{2488320 \,i^4}+O\left(\frac{1}{i^5}\right)\Bigg)$$  and
$$\sum_{i=1}^p \frac { e^{\alpha \,i}}{i^{n+\frac{1}{2}} }=\text{Li}_{n+\frac{1}{2}}\left(e^{\alpha }\right)-e^{\alpha  (p+1)}\,\,\Phi \left(e^{\alpha },n+\frac{1}{2},p+1\right)$$ where appear the polylogarithm function and the Lerch transcendent function.
